# MVC5 ModelClientValidationRegexRule always failing

Tags: c#, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-5, validationattribute

In my custom validation attribute I Have the following:

```
yield return new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(_invalidCharactersErrorMessage, "/^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+$/i");
```

It is suppose to accept only letters, numbers and spaces.  Now on the HTML side of things, here is what gets generated:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Only letters, numbers, and spaces are allowed" data-val-regex-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/i" data-val-required="Alias is required" id="Alias" name="Alias" placeholder="Alias" type="text" value="" >
```

When I type in the field, it always gets activated and I see the error message no matter what I type in.  Is my regex wrong or is there something else at play here?  From what I've read online, my regex seems to be correct

Comment: Note that you do not need `/i` at all since you already defined `A-Za-z`. Try passing a simple string pattern `"^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+$"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acc. to [this resource](https://web.archive.org/web/20130919030425/http://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/some-things-ive-learned-about-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/), the value you pass inside `data-val-regex-pattern` is a string pattern, not a regex object, and it is already anchored.

So, since you already added lowercase ASCII letters to your character class, you can just use

```
yield return new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(_invalidCharactersErrorMessage, "[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+");
```

or (since doubling `^` and `$` does no harm), you may also try `"^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+$"`

Comment: I tested it and you are correct, I didn't pass the ^ nor the $ and it works.  Thank you!